# NetSuite Script 2.0 Custom Field on the Customer Address Sublist not scriptable

Tags: netsuite

i am not able to get the Custom Field on the Customer Address Sublist or update it using sscript 2.0.

in the address form that field is showing and i can update it.

but in script 2.0 i can not get its value or set it.

Answer (score -1):

custom fields on the address record are a sublist of the address record.  If you are on a customer and there is a sublist that is the address record, then you would be accessing a sublist of a sublist to reach the custom field you are talking about.

I don't believe that is possible.  You could try starting your script on the address record and joining it to the customer record and then the sublist of the custom fields if you still need to make that connection.

See the custom field sublist entry in the schema:

http://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2016_1/schema/record/address.html